# Frame rate when moving input.MousePosition

Tags: unity-game-engine, frame, mouse-position

Why is it that when the Input.MousePosition of frames is accelerated, it drops quickly and the actions performed at this moment are performed several times less often, let's say we spawn the object, when the mouse is moved slowly, the detours will spawn perfectly, and if we move the mesh to another point faster, then we will spawn these detours less often by 3-4 times, depending on the speed of the jerk?

```
public GameObject prefab;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        SpawnPoint();
    }
}
public void SpawnPoint()
{
    Transform inst = Instantiate(prefab).transform;

    inst.position = (Vector2)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
}
```

Here's what happens in the game itself
1 when moving slowly
2 with a quick jerk of movement
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwC63.png)

Comment: Of course the frame rate will be different. Between doing nothing and spawning objects.  Spawning objects is a semi costly set of instructions. You’re doing it constantly while holding the mouse down.

Comment: And why is everything fine with a slow mouse movement, and if you move the cursor sharply, the frame rate decreases at this moment

Comment: Frame rate means how many frames per seconds. So `move faster` = `less time` = `less frames`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for user input in `Update()` instead of `FixedUpdate()`

The reason you typically get user input in `Update` is because it runs once per frame, where `FixedUpdate` does not - it runs per physics tick, and more or less than one of those may occur each frame.

So a general rule is to get user input in `Update` and handle the physics related stuff in `FixedUpdate`.

Then in your `SpawnPoint` you are instantiating an object and `Instantiate()` is little bit expensive plus `Camera.main` will try to find camera every physics frame by doing `FindGameObjectsWithTag()` so you should also cache `Camera` into a variable instead.